# could not build custom configured nginx

Tags: server, nginx, makefile

I am using UBUNTU server 22.04, openssl version 3.0.2 and I was trying to build custom configured NGINX as a proxy for mail server however, when I run 'make' it gives me error. For that i referred to these sources:

https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-build-nginx-from-source-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts_597793

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/mail-proxy/mail-proxy/

http://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html

I downloaded NGINX source code using command: `wget  http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.21.6.tar.gz`

After extracting and changing directory I ran a customized command:

`./configure --prefix=/var/www/html --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --with-pcre  --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --modules-path=/etc/nginx/modules --with-http_v2_module --with-stream=dynamic --with-http_addition_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl/`

But after this when I run 'make' command the I get error that is:

> make -f objs/Makefile make[1]: Entering directory
> '/home/ubuntu/nginx-build/nginx-1.21.6' cd /usr/include/openssl/ \ &&
> if [ -f Makefile ]; then make clean; fi \ && ./config
> --prefix=/usr/include/openssl//.openssl no-shared no-threads  \ && make \ && make install_sw LIBDIR=lib /bin/sh: 3: ./config: not found
> make[1]: *** [objs/Makefile:1705:
> /usr/include/openssl//.openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h] Error 127
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/nginx-build/nginx-1.21.6'
> make: *** [Makefile:10: build] Error 2

**My assumption:**
I think this error is occurring because I am giving wrong path to `--with-openssl` parameter. If that is the case kindly specify how to find correct path which I should assign this parameter or if there is other issue then please give me solution to that.

Comment: The instructions you've linked are only applicable if you're installing nginx from source - if you're using the packaged version from the Ubuntu repository then you *probably* just need to install the [libnginx-mod-mail](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libnginx-mod-mail) package.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to point NginX's `./configure` script at your installed version of OpenSSL, when you actually need to download the source code [[https://www.openssl.org/source](https://www.openssl.org/source/)], unpack it to it's own directory, and then point `--with-openssl` to that directory. This will cause `make` to build both NginX and OpenSSL from source in one go.

**If you want to use your installed version of OpenSSL, just omit `--with-openssl` altogether, and continue on your way.**

With that said, @steeldriver is probably correct about not needing to build NginX from scratch if only because maintaining a custom build can be a pain.

Edit: Some further explanation and context:

`--with-http_ssl_module`: This flag tells the `.\configure` script that you want to enable HTTPS protocol support within NginX. By itself it will use the system installed OpenSSL version.

`--with-openssl`: This flag tells `.\configure` to build OpenSSL from source with NginX, and *not* to use the system installed version, it is generally used with the `--with-openssl-opt` flag to customize the OpenSSL build as well as being a good way to use a newer version of OpenSSL that might not be supported by your OS.

Most (if not all) build flags are described in the Nginx docs, specifically here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/configure.html

Comment: Luis, I tried taking out the --with-openssl, and configure fails with the error "./configure: error: SSL modules require the OpenSSL library.
You can either do not enable the modules, or install the OpenSSL library
into the system, or build the OpenSSL library statically from the source
with nginx by using --with-openssl=<path> option."  But I have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3